# Extract elements from html table using java script

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

```
<tbody class='detail' onclick='singleDelayCall(toggleDetail, event, this)'><tr><td Class='cluster' rowspan='539'>core</td>
<td Class='name' rowspan='539'>bilateral_1t_throttle0</td>
<td Class='result-name '>timing: cycles</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>31787.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>4967.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>33695.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>4967.0</td>
</tr><tr class='detail-hide'><td Class='result-name '>pmu: COUNTER0_OVERFLOW</td>
<td Class='' title='' lastPassTag=''>&nbsp;</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>0.0</td>
<td Class='' title='' lastPassTag=''>&nbsp;</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>0.0</td>
</tr><tr class='detail-hide'><td Class='result-name '>pmu: COUNTER2_OVERFLOW</td>
<td Class='' title='' lastPassTag=''>&nbsp;</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>0.0</td>
<td Class='' title='' lastPassTag=''>&nbsp;</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>0.0</td>
</tr><tr class='detail-hide'><td Class='result-name '>pmu: COMMITTED_PKT_ANY</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
```

I want to extract numbers 31787.0,4967.0,33695.0,4967.0 only which are under merit class . They are a part of `<tr> class='cluster'</tr>` . I do not want the numbers which are under merit but not under `<tr> class='cluster'</tr>`.
I have tried this , but it does not work

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('cluster')[0];
zlen=list.getElementsByClassName('metric')[0].innerHTML; 
for (var i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
      z = zlen[i].innerHTML;
      document.writeln(z);
```

Any modifications or suggestions are appreciated .
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're only selecting the first element of the `metric` class!
What you need to change:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName('cluster')[0];
zlen=list.getElementsByClassName('metric'); 
for (var i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
      z = zlen[i].innerHTML;
      document.writeln(z);
```

**EDIT:** I've made a fiddle for you [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxm1kp6y/)

> Do note:
>
> - I've changed `Class` to `class`
> - And changed the `class='cluster'` from a `td` to a `tr`